# how to fix "value below was evaluated just now" in angular 7

Tags: php, angular, angular7

I keep getting an "i" icon beside the array

[image]

the ngFor doesn't display the items on first load unless I click the pagination. then that's the time it will show up the whole list.

is it because of that `value below was evaluated just now` , anyway to fix this in angular 7 ?

What my code does for this component is that,
1) At the main component template i have a property binding 
e.g `[thisIstheDataForThisComponent] = thisIsTheData`

2) then in the component for this code, i loop over the contents of `thisIstheDataForThisComponent` since it is labeled as an @Input Decorator in the component.

I have done this same style of property binding in other parts of the application, but only this array is not displaying on first load

Here's my **Service** code to pull data

```
  public getData(url, headers): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(config.SERVICE_URL + url, headers)
    .pipe(
      delay(300),
      map((data: any) => (data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

here's my code in the **parent** component

```
  public thisIstheDataForThisComponent= { count: 0, data: [] };

    let myHttpOptions= {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'HTTP_TOKEN': 'ASDF2SOMERANDOMTOKENHERE'
      })
    };

  this.myCustomService.getData('/apiController/getData', myHttpOptions).subscribe((data) => {

    if (data != '') {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.data.push({  
            country: data.data[i].country,
            total: data.data[i].total,
            numstuff: data.data[i].numstuff,
            blahstuff: data.data[i].blahstuff,
            thisstuff: data.data[i].thisstuff,
            thatstuff: data.data[i].thatstuff
          });
        }   
        this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.count = data.data.length;   
      }

  });
      this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.data = this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.data;
      this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.count = this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent.count;
```

then here is the **parent** component template

```
                <article class="col-sm12">
                  <my-widget [thisIstheDataForThisComponent]='thisIstheDataForThisComponent'></my-widget>
                </article>
```

here is the **child** component

```
  @Input()thisIstheDataForThisComponent: any;
```

then in the **child** component template

```
 <tr *ngFor="let items of thisIstheDataForThisComponent.data"><!--START TR-->
```

Comment: Can you please share the code which shows how are you filling thisIsTheData property in your parent component? Is it filled by an Observable.subscribe()?

Comment: I have modified my post and included some code snippets. can you help check what am doing wrong?

Comment: yes it is filled by and observable subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would request you to try followings -

**1.**
It appears that in your parent or child component you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. If it is there then can you please try your code after removing the changeDetection line from your `@Component` decorator [from both components]. If it works then you need to understand how "OnPush" works. OnPush Change Detection will run the angular change detection cycle only when the bound property "REFERENCE" changes [See https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/ for more details]

**2.**
If #1 does not work then try updating the code like this -

Have a property in your observable like this -

```
public thisIstheDataForThisComponent$: Observable<{ count: 0, data: [] }>;
```

Now in ngOnInit() setup that observable property like this -

```
ngOnInit() {

    let myHttpOptions= {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'HTTP_TOKEN': 'ASDF2SOMERANDOMTOKENHERE'
      })
    };

    this.thisIstheDataForThisComponent$ = this.myCustomService.getData('/apiController/getData', myHttpOptions)
                                              .pipe(
                                                map(data => {
                                                  const retVal = { count: 0, data: [] };
                                                  if(data) {                                                    

                                                    data.data.forEach(d => {
                                                      retVal.data.push(
                                                        {  
                                                          country: d.country,
                                                          total: d.total,
                                                          numstuff: d.numstuff,
                                                          blahstuff: d.blahstuff,
                                                          thisstuff: d.thisstuff,
                                                          thatstuff: dthatstuff
                                                        }
                                                      )
                                                    });

                                                    retVal.count = data.data.length;
                                                  }

                                                  return retVal;
                                                })
                                              );

  }
```

Now in your parent component template do the following change -

```
<article class="col-sm12">
        <my-widget [thisIstheDataForThisComponent]="thisIstheDataForThisComponent$ | async"></my-widget>
</article>
```

Notice the `async` pipe which takes care of subscribe/unsubscribe automatically.

Hope this solution should solve your issue or at least it will give you a direction to solve your issue.

Comment: where di you get the async pipe?

Comment: @sasori async pipe is defined in CommonModule from @angular/common. See the official docs at - https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: i don't have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` ..but your solution worked with the async pipe..thanks a lot @user2216584

Answer (score -2):

try initializing an array with `countries = [];`

Comment: initializing it with [] didn''t help at all